# Ionic 4 Firebase Pushnotification

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4

I need to know is it possible to need to send some type ID with firebase notification. Where user get notification i want to open the page and pass that ID as a parameter in api ? Is it possible ? OR any one have example ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your need you can send a notification message, or data message, the notification message will be basically responsible for showing a push notification to the device with a title, subtitle and message depending on the operating system (in terms of the graphic environment), the data message will send a notification to the device with the data you want, this notification will not be visible to the user, now if you need to send data but also show a notification to the user you can do it in two ways:

1. You send a notification of data, when you receive it you process it, you show a local notification and you send by parameter the id that you received.
2. Send a push notification (with the id specifically in some side as you wish) this is shown by default to the user, when the user opens it, you process the id, and send it by parameter.

I recommend the first option, here you will find more information

[Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging)